# ios link to page from image

Tags: ios, image, anchor

I would really like to know how can I add an anchor to an image in an iOS application. The anchor would point to some page.

It would look like this on the web:

`<a href="www.somepage.com"><img src="myimage.jpg"/></a>`

thanks

Comment: #define "somePage"?? do you mean some ViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)foo
{
...
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
}

-(void)btnPressed:(UIButton*)sender {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nba.com"];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I really dont see how is this going to link me to another page, by clicking on the image.

Answer (score 1):

### .....

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget: action:@selector(btnPressedToOpenUrl) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

-(void)btnPressedToOpenUrl
{
UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
 NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.somepage.com" ];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```